# Electronic bands and Aufbau principle

Tags: solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, electronic-band-theory, orbitals

In atomic theory there is [Aufbau principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle) stating (Wikipedia)

> The rule states that for a given electron configuration, the lowest energy term is the one with the greatest value of spin multiplicity. This implies that if two or more orbitals of equal energy are available, electrons will occupy them singly before filling them in pairs.

In elementary treatment of electronic band structures, spin is treated as an internal degree of freedom and does not enter the Hamiltonian, resulting is the solutions to be doubly degenerate corresponding to spin. The only place where spin may play a role is in the supposition of an totally antisymmetric many-body state.

I imagine that for band insulators the question of order of filling at zero temperature does not matter. In metals, at zero temperature, I also imagine the electrons filling up doubly-occupied single particle states to the Fermi level. Although I am not quite clear if that is indeed the case, since perhaps the antisymmetry may require alternative filling.

However, the band filling order may play a role in temperature dependence, since if a rule of the sort of Aufbau principle holds, the electrons are first excited to form a band of singly occupied electrons before a double-excitation occurs.

My question is: does the order at which electronic states in crystals are filled depend on spin?